# Convert default emojis to custom png

Tags: javascript, html, css, utf-8, emoji

I have chat application, where now I have default browser emojis integrated. Now I want to change it with custom png emojis. So how can I convert it? should I parse each and every chat message and swap default emoji with custom one? maybe there is better solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use custom pngs then yes, you should parse loop and replace.

Emojis are treated the same as regular characters on a system level, whereas png is an image and thus completely different.

If you are thinking about overriding the system's default mapping of `emoji char code` => `emoji` with your custom pngs, as far as I know you are out of luck. The closest thing I can think of is creating a font which defines custom glyphs for some emojis, but of course you can't use coloured images as glyphs, so you're stuck with mono-colour.